# Complete Checkout API gives error "Cannot complete the checkout without any transactions shopify"

Tags: shopify, checkout, shopify-app, checkout-payments

I am using the sales channel for process the checkout in shopify website. I have created checkout and updated the shipping lines and discount also implemented the paypal standard payment gateway. after making the successful payment a new order is created but after creating the order  , I want to complete checkout and it gives error like 
`'base' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'code' => 'missing_transactions',
      'message' => 'Cannot complete the checkout without any transactions.',
      'options' => 
      array (
      ),
    ),
  ),`

How to add transaction details in checkout without calling the payment API of shopify ? as I have already made the payment using paypal standard payment gateway.

I have review the documentation of shopify

https://help.shopify.com/en/api/guides/sales-channel-sdk/completing-a-payment#send-credit-card-information-using-a-third-party-service

They are talking to use https://www.spreedly.com/ for external payment page.where we need to POST the payment information(card,cvv,expiry date etc.) to https://www.spreedly.com/ and get payment session _id and same need to post the shopify.

But I don't want to use any third party API for session_id. I want to post the transaction data directly to shopify checkout. is it possible?

Can anyone help me ?.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at the moment. If you want to complete a checkout you must use payment API. The other option is to create orders by your own, in that case you do not need a checkout.